# Можно ли сделать на swift 3 так, чтобы все страницы отображались в портретной ориентации и только одна — и портретной и landscape?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, mobile-development

Добрый день!
Пришло задание сделать приложение, где бы все страницы отображались в портретной ориентации, и только одна (фотографии) и портретной и landscape. Возможно ли это сделать на swift 3 или в ios такое не делается?

Comment: если ответ помог, отметьте его галочкой

Answer (score 0):

Можно. Просто пропишите в нужных контроллерах с портретной ориентацией:

```
override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    return false
}
```

И добавьте необходимые `supportedInterfaceOrientations`:

```
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .portrait
}
```